# The precision of internal voltage reference in PIC

Tags: pic, precision, reference

I am designing some circuit with [PIC16F18345](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC16F18345) and I need some voltage reference (±0.5% or better). I can add some external reference or use built-in internal voltage reference in that MCU (that means simpler design and saved 1 IO pin).
What is the precision of that voltage reference? I am not able to find this info anywhere.

Datasheet:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001795C.pdf

Comment: Bottom of page 430 - Table 35-16. Prepare to be disappointed.

Comment: Well, that is embarrassing ;) I have overlooked it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, 4% is quite a bit disappointing :(